# How to know when a A-Synchronous REST call in Windows 8.1 Mobile Library has been completed?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, async-await

**Background::**

1. I am creating a Windows 8.1 Mobile SDK that will have a License Manager(LM) Module.
2. The client will have to Call The License Manager in their code once whenever the application starts.
3. The license manager will register the client and send a set of JSON Response that will be stored on the device for future validations.
4. The License Manager function makes REST Calls to our server.

**Problem::**

1. What will be the best place within a Windows 8.1 application to call the License Manager Function provided in the SDK?
2. How to make the call to the LM Synchronous, so that the client gets a chance to handle responses in case the license is not validated. Or before the client calls the other APIs included in the SDK.

**Work Done::**

3. I have created the LM function and returns the desired results.
4. Created a Demo App that calls the LM on a button click.

Please find the sample code below,

**Client Application:**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var x = await sdk.InitializeAsync("xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx");
            //Calling an API included in the SDK
            APIResponse res = await laas.Function1_Async(par1, par2);          

            msg.Text = x.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

**SDK:**

```
public async Task<int> InitializeAsync(string apiKey)
    {
        int status = 0;

        if (!_isInitialized)
        {    
                status = await GetLicenseInfo(localSettings);
        }
        this._isInitialized = true;

        return status;
    }

     private async Task<int> GetLicenseInfo(Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings)
    {
        APIResponse res = new APIResponse();
        res.Status = -10;
        res.Message = "Unknown Error!";

        // Create the web request            
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.Append(*JSON String*);
        string Uri = _regisUrl;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(Uri);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = url.Host;
            try
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                        //Check that the Response is Success
                        if (res.Status == 1)
                            localSettings.Values["IsDeviceRegistered"] = StringCipher.Encrypt("registered");                            
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        return res.Status;
    }
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't the answer to your question just "put it after the `await laas.Function1_Async()` line"?

Answer (score 1):

This will change your code to be Synchronous...

```
        Task<int> t = sdk.InitializeAsync("xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx");
        t.Wait();
        var myvalue = t.Result;            
        .....
```

Comment: Stuart, I tried it. My UI Thread freezes and the application crashes :\

Comment: Yes that is correct, a synchronous call will cause the UI thread to freeze. It sounds like you want to know when your task is complete. You will need to add an Event to your class to get this to work. I like to use actions for this